# Android Studio: Unable to Start AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, qemu

I have installed Android Studio, but I am Unable to start run any of the sample applications on the net. Under AVD Manager after selecting the AVD to run, it shows the AVD dialog with a black screen and the word "android" at the centre of the screen. When I try to run the sample applications, it takes a long time (about 4-6 minutes),  after which a Windows error message appears

"qemu-system-x86_64.exe has stopped working"

[image]

I have also noticed the following messages on the console everytime I try to run the AVD from theAVD Manager.

```
Could not load func glBindFramebuffer
Could not load func glGenFramebuffers
Could not load func glFramebufferTexture2D
Hax is enabled
Could not load func glCheckFramebufferStatus
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Could not load func glDeleteFramebuffers
Could not load func glIsRenderbuffer
Could not load func glBindRenderbuffer
Could not load func glDeleteRenderbuffers
Could not load func glGenRenderbuffers
Could not load func glRenderbufferStorage
Could not load func glGetRenderbufferParameteriv
Could not load func glFramebufferRenderbuffer
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Installation details

1. Android Studio: Version 2.0
2. OS: Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit

Answer (score 2):

Android studio is quite heavy Software so it takes much more RAM of your PC. And as you are creating AVD it takes much time for first time but from next start 2 minutes are enough. But I will suggest you should go for third party emulator such as Genymotion to run Genymotion you need to make sure that your machine supports Virtualization and its Virtual bit is on. You also need to install VirtalBox then Install Genymotion. Its an much much faster Emulator for android.

1.You can download genymotion form https://www.genymotion.com/thank-you-freemium/

2.You can download VirtualBox form https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: I would have liked to know why I am having those problems with AVDs. For now, I have been able to connect to my real phone and it suffices for now. But since I need virtual devices, I will later install genymotion as advised and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Oh spent a day finding a solution.Just select software GLES from the Emulated performance in AVD settings..and your are done..!

Comment: Which AVD Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and setting the graphics rendering from Automatic to Software fixed it. 
Go to `AVD Manager`, `Edit` the AVD, and look under `Startup orientation`, there is a section called `Emulated Performance`. Select `Software - GLES 2.0`.

This fixes the issue but I find it odd, since I never had problems running the machines with automatic acceleration before. 
No hardware changes, since the last time it worked. Only worth considering software changes are: updated Android Studio to 2.2, updated the Intel Emulator Accelerator to 6.0.4 and changed the OS to Windows 10.

btw: I usually use Genymotion, as it is lighter than the Android Studio machines. If you want to use the google services, maps and so on, you have to modify the Genymotion VMs. Or you can use the Android Studio VMs as they are.